# How to use both variations of QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, multithreading

Trying to understand both variations of `ThreadPool` method `QueueUserWorkItem`.

```
string bigS = "Big Stupid";
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( s =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Working on a thread from threadpool B");
    Console.WriteLine("s = {0}", s.ToString());
}, bigS);

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MethodA, bigS);
```

`MethodA` is defined like this.

```
private static void MethodA(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("o = {0}", o.ToString());
}
```

Both ways are fine. But there is another variation of `QueueUserWorkItem` that takes delegate of a method which takes single parameter and return void. So `methodA` should be fine. But following code throw exception since I am not passing the object `o` in `MethodA`. I don't want to check null for `o` in `MethodA`. How can I pass `bigS` in 2nd case to `MethodA`?

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MethodA);
```

Alternative way could be like this. But I would like to pass and access `o`. Can I achieve this?

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( o =>
{
Console.WriteLine("Working on a thread from threadpool");
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, you want to call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MethodA);` but you still want `bigS` passed in to MethodA?

Comment: Just check the object to see if it is null first, before attempting to call `ToString()` on it.  No, you can't avoid that, if there's any possibility that the object can be null.  There are shortcuts available to make such checks easier; see http://www.dotnetperls.com/null-coalescing

Comment: I know if I want to use o in production code, I need to guard it, I am just experimenting how can I use other variation of QueueUserWorkItem which take a method with a parameter, just checking if I can pass that parameter somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear from the MSDN documentation, but

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback);
```

is equivalent to

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback, null);
```

If optional parameters existed at the time this API has been made, most probably there would have been just one method like

```
public static bool QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback callBack, object state = null)
```

But for one thing the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct(v=vs.110).aspx) (the **Remarks** section) is clear - if you want your callback to receive something, you need to pass it, i.e. use the overload with `state` argument.

Answer (score 1):

The o in

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( o =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Working on a thread from threadpool");
});
```

will always be null. It is just there because `QueueUserWorkItem` wants a `WaitCallback` and that is defined as an `Action<object>`. I think microsoft devs just don´t wanted to define a second `WaitCallback` delegate. And `ThreadPool` was implemented before `Action` and `Func` existed.

You could capture the `bigS` with your lambda

```
string bigS = "Big Stupid";
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( _ =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Working on a thread from threadpool B");
    Console.WriteLine("s = {0}", bigS);
});
```

or like this if you have to use `MethodA`

```
string bigS = "Big Stupid";
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( _ =>
{
    MethodA(bigS);
});
```